# Error: Cannot find module './internal/streams/stream'

Tags: node.js, angular, sweetalert2

I'm trying to add Sweetalert2 component in Angular to my project.
When I put the npm install sweetalert2 in the terminal the following problem occurs:

> Error: Cannot find module './internal/streams/stream'

and I don't know how to solve it.

This is the Error in the terminal:

[image: This is the Error in the terminal]

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was
deleting the `package-lock.json`
and the `node_modules` folder and
then running

```sh
npm install
```

Then running:

```sh
npm install sweetalert2
```

Or if you don't want to deal with this one put the url of the cdn in the html file you request like this:

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete your `node_modules` by running:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

2. Delete your `package-lock.json`
3. Clear your npm cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

4. Run:

```
npm install
```